# Backbone.js View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm learning Backbone.js now. I'm writing mvc Todo list for study.
I have a code like this:

```
   var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tasks',
    model: Todo,
    events: {
        'click > li .delete-task' : 'removeTask',
        'click > li .complete-task' : 'completeTask'
    },
    removeTask : function () {
        console.log(this.get('model'));
    },
    completeTask : function () {

    }
});
```

So, I can't get .delete-task, when was a click.
For example, If i click on .delete-task in third li, I want to get a third li.
How I can realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `currentTarget` to do the trick.

```
TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tasks',
    events: {
        'click .delete-task' : 'removeTask'
    },
    removeTask : function (e) {
        alert($(e.currentTarget).text())
    },
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gwgxxopo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I find an answer.
I should write a code like this:

```
var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#tasks',
        model: Todo,
        events: {
            'click > li .delete-task' : 'removeTask',
            'click > li .complete-task' : 'completeTask'
        },
        removeTask : function (e) {
            console.log($(e.target));
        },
        completeTask : function () {

        }
    });
```

`$(e.target)` is current element.